# Calculating the expected bounce height of a golf ball on a surface of varying thickness of polyethersulfone (PES)

Tags: energy, gravity, collision

I'm trying to calculate how high a golf ball will bounce when dropped onto a surface made of polyethersulfone (PES) with a given drop height.

Given a drop height of one meter, how can I calculate how high the ball will bounce if it is dropped on different parts of a surface made out of PES of varying thickness? A diagram of the surface is shown below, the arrows indicate the different drop locations. For simplicity we can assume a drop height of 1 meter:

[image]

Because both the golf ball and PES will flex upon impact, I am trying to figure out how to apply Young's modulus and Hooke's law to determine how the different thicknesses will impact the bounce height. But the equation that links Young's modulus to Hooke's Law requires the surface area to be part of the calculation...

Hooke's Law:

[image]

Young's Modulus:

[image]

(Can be reworked to relate it to `k` from Hooke's law)

[image]

Where `A` is the surface area of PES, and `Lo` is the thickness of the material before compression.

Since the golf ball is going to have a very precise impact I would think that the energy will not be evenly distributed across the surface so using the surface area of the entire surface might not give accurate results. Also the fact that the surface gradually changes in thickness and is not all one thickness is making it difficult to figure out exactly how to apply the equations to it.

---

I found the Young's modulus (`E`) value for PES here:
https://dielectricmfg.com/knowledge-base/polyethersulfone/

`2.41e9 - 2.83e9 Pa`

Although it seems to give a range so and not a single value so I'm not sure which number to use.

---

This leads to a few questions:

1. How does the gradual varying thickness of the surface impact the math that needs to be done when determining the bounce height.
2. How do I properly calculate the amount of energy lost in the impact depending on where the ball strikes the surface (I assume the thicker the material the more spring-like it will be and the less energy will be lost?)
3. Which value for Young's modulus should I use for PES since the internet seems to just provide a range and not one distinct value?
4. Since the golf ball will also compress on impact, how do I calculate how much the golf ball will compress and how much energy will be stored/released in that compression?
5. And finally, Is there additional information needed to actually effectively calculate the expected bounce height? (other than obvious things like the value of acceleration due to gravity)

Comment: Not that I am qualified to answer your question, but what (if anything) supports your PES slab? In my casual experience of dropping balls onto surfaces to see what bounces, if the surface is _thin,_ and if it is free to vibrate, that can have a dramatic impact on the elasticity of the collision.

Comment: @SolomonSlow for the sake of simplicity let's assume that it is firmly secure to something that will not move and it will not be free to vibrate. After figuring out the math without accounting for vibration I will do some basic real world testing and if the tests don't line up with the math I will consider adding more complexities to the calculation.